# Spaces that satisfy closure with respect to addition and scalar multiplication but aren't vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

This question is probably a silly one, but I'm not the greatest at coming up with counterexamples. Perhaps someone can lend some insight.

The usual (I think?) definition of a vector space $V$ is a space which is closed with respect to (vector) addition and scalar multiplication (with scalars taken from some field $\mathbb{K}$) and upon which these operations satisfy a number of algebraic axioms (which I won't list here but which are listed [elsewhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition)). So my question:

Can someone give an example of a pair $(V,\mathbb{K})$ consisting of a space $V$ which is closed with respect to addition and multiplication by elements of **a field** $\mathbb{K}$ but which *isn't* a vector space due to it not satisfying any/all of the vector space axioms? I tried Googling such a thing as well as searching for various related phrases here in SXE but I had no luck.

Any information would be hugely appreciated!

**Edit:** In the third paragraph, I *do* still want $\mathbb{K}$ to be a field. I've added that to the paragraph itself.

Comment: I wonder. Do you still want $\mathbb{K}$ to be a field in your third paragraph? If not, you could search about R-Modules or group actions.

Comment: @DavidMolano - Thank you for pointing out my carelessness! I've edited the question to indicate my intention (which was for $\mathbb{K}$ to be a field).

Comment: Just define any two functions $V\times V\to V$ and $\mathbb K\times V\to V$ and call them addition and scalar multiplication. Odds are, they won't satisfy the axioms. For example, take $V=\mathbb R^n$, $\mathbb K=\mathbb R$, $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)+(y_1,\ldots,y_n)=(x_1-y_1,\ldots,x_n-y_n)$, and $a\cdot(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(a+x_1,\ldots,a+x_n)$.

Comment: @Rahul - I knew that my question must have been a silly one, but your answer has illustrated how unequivocally true that sentiment is. Thanks for taking the time to reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K$ be $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and consider the action on $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ where $1\cdot a=4a$, $2\cdot a=2a$ for $a\in\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. This turns $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ into a $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ module, but this module is not unital hence is not a vector space.

Comment: This is precisely the sort of answer I'd hoped for! I notice that this is a very algebraic counterexample: I wonder, then, if this can be generalized for general fields $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, for various rings $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ ($p$ = prime), and for miscellaneous operations between them? I'm choosing this as the best answer regardless, but if you happen to know of generaliations of your counterexample, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: @twigg1313 I've always thought this example was cool, but I've never looked for generalizations.

Comment: @twigg1313 There are other nontrivial examples. We could take any $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ module and have $\mathbb{R}$ act on it by having $a\in\mathbb{R}$ act as $(a,0)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. Again, it isn't unital.

Comment: @twigg131 Actually now that I think about it that is the same as my answer, where we treat $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Take a module over a direct product ring where one of the factors is a field, and have an element $a$ of the field act as $(a,0,0,\ldots,0)$.

Comment: Excellent observation! I'm going to be getting on a plane soon and I'm going to spend that time tinkering with generalizations (of the flavor I mentioned) as well because I'm sure they must exist. :D

Answer (score 2):

For example $V$ could be the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are real, under the usual addition, and we could have $r(a,b)=(0,0)$ for all reals $r$, $a$, and $b$.

Comment: This is indeed a very worthwhile and very general answer. I of course didn't mention triviality of the example, etc., because I wanted to see a wide variety of counterexamples; even so, I'm going to upvote but save "accepting" it to see whether there are less-trivial examples provided. Many thanks!